# What Windows OS does ArcGIS Desktop perform best on?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation

I'm planning to install ArcGIS Desktop 10.6 on a completely clean system that will only be used for GIS. The system meets the requirements for 10.6, but as stated by [ESRI](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/setup/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements.htm), 10.6 can be installed on Windows 7, 8, 10 or Windows Server 2008, 2012 or 2016. Since I'm almost totally flexible, I'm interested what OS Desktop performs best on.

Is there any evidence to support one version of Windows over another when choosing to install ArcGIS for Desktop on a Windows machine?

Comment: There is no best operating system, just enterprise management preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft discontinued mainstream support for Windows 7 in 2015 and will end extended support on Jan 14, 2020, so that would rule out Windows 7 ([source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet#section_2)). Similarly, Microsoft ended mainstream support for Windows 8.1 on January 2018 and will end extended support in 2023--this would also rule out version 8.1 for me ([source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet#section_2)). That leaves Windows 10.

There is no reason to run ArcGIS for Desktop on a Windows Server, unless you have specific needs such as making spatial data available to others via web services. In that case, you would likely want to be running ArcGIS Server.

Stick with Windows 10 if you have a standard ArcGIS Desktop install.

Comment: You've presented a fair case for Windows 10, which answers the question as asked. Thanks. I was hoping for a quantitive, empirical, data-driven analysis... like benchmarking the same ArcMap operations on the same system but with different versions of Windows. Maybe that analysis hasn't been done!

Answer (score -2):

Since ArcGIS 10.6 released on 2018, so best OS is desktop OS windows in this era/period, i my self and my friend prefer to user windows pro/ enterprise 10.
Previously i'm using windows 7 , but with this you should add more required tools, which already bundled in windows 10.